# Get ID of row from database where the data was inserted

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm running a MySQL INSERT query where I insert some data into the database.
Each row has a unique ID generated each time a new entry is added. I'd like to get this ID straight after I insert the data.

PHP Code:

```
$addGiveawayToDb = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(orientation, title, color) 
    VALUES ('$orientation', '$title', '$color')") 
    or die(mysql_error());
//Here I need to get the row id of the above data...
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's the 2nd result when you paste your question into Google...

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer What was the first result?

Answer (score 4):

Try like

```
$addGiveawayToDb = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(orientation, title, color) 
VALUES ('$orientation', '$title', '$color')") 
or die(mysql_error());

echo "Inserted Id is ".mysql_insert_id();
```

Makesure that you have an auto increment field in your table.And also try to avoid `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements.

See this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)